# Domain user access to SQL Server Reporting Services 2005 on IIS 7

Tags: sql-server-2005, iis-7, reportingservices-2005

What are the required steps to properly allow domain users access to reports via the Reporting Services web site?

**What I've tried:**

- Added users through Reporting Services site (i.e. http://servername/Reports)
- Given users access through SQL Management Studio

**Result:**

- users are continuously prompted by the browser for their credentials and can't log in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been dealing with this exact issue recently. I still don't *know* the answer, but I *think* that at least part of it is to add the users to SSRS-specific groups (create them if needed through the SSRS Configuration manager).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How exactly do I add users to SSRS-specific groups?

Comment: Sorry, you actually answered the question. I just didn't get it at first. :P

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why I didn't think of this before but I:

- Added desired domain users to the "SQLServer2005ReportServerUser*$InstanceName*" group on the Windows 2008 machine running SQL Server Reporting Services
- Added users to specific roles through reporting services web site (http://servername/reports)

AND now users are able to access the reporting services site!